# How do you find the intercepts of 2 some functions

Tags: trigonometry

I

\begin{align*} &H(y) = 600 \sin (2\pi/3\cdot (y-0.25)) + 1000   \qquad & \text{(Birds)}\\
& H(y) = 320 \sin (2\pi/7\cdot y) + 500   \qquad   & \text{(Mustelids)}
\end{align*}

Comment: When you want to find the intersection points of two given functions $f$ and $g$, you want to solve the equation $f(x)=g(x)$, or equivalently $f(x)-g(x)=0$, for $x$. How one then finds a solution to such an equation, is another pair of shoes.

Comment: I did that initially and got stuck. Do you have any idea how to make y/x the subject?

Comment: Check WA: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+y+600+%5Csin+(2%5Cpi%2F3%5Ccdot+(y-0.25))+%2B+1000+++%3D+320+%5Csin+(2%5Cpi%2F7%5Ccdot+y)+%2B+500 . I mean, using duplication and addition formulas for $\sin$ just looks like a huge mess. But maybe I am wrong

Comment: This system has period 21 in $y$. There are 4 intervals each period when the mustelid population is greater. Are you interested in all of them?

Comment: The exact question once you have both equations is 'if this model applies over an extended period, find the times when the mustelid population is higher than the bird population?'

Answer (score 1):

So, you have two functions $$f(x)=600 \sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}   \left(y-\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)+1000$$ $$g(x)=320 \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi }{7}y\right)+500$$ Plotting the functions, you see that they cross eachother an infinite number of times and you are able to locate them more or less accurately.

So, now, you are looking for the zero's of $$h(x)=600 \sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}  \left(y-\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)-320 \sin
   \left(\frac{2 \pi  }{7}y\right)+500$$

Only numerical methods will allow you to solve the problem. Probably the simplest would be Newton method which, starting from a "reasonable" guess $y_0$, will update it according to $$y_{n+1}=y_n-\frac{h(y_n)}{h'(y_n)}$$ For this problem $$h'(x)=400 \pi  \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}
   \left(y-\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)-\frac{640}{7} \pi  \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi 
   }{7}y\right)$$

Let us apply the method for the first positive root using $y_0=2$; the method generates the following iterates $\{1.890686453,1.897805832,1.897828411\}$ and we obtained the solution in three iterations for ten significant figures.

Let us repeat for the second root using $y_0=3$; the method generates the following iterates $\{2.954599701,2.953387580,2.953386630\}$; again, three iterations for ten significant figures.